# Difference between background view and content view in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone

Hi what is the difference between content view and background view in a uitableviewcell?

As I have read in the apple docs I understand that the content view property is the superview for the content but what is the background view for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contentView:`

> The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell.

`backgroundView:`

> The default is nil for cells in plain-style tables (UITableViewStylePlain) and non-nil for grouped-style tables UITableViewStyleGrouped). UITableViewCell adds the background view as a subview behind all other views and uses its current frame location.

Courtesy of the [UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: The worst explanation I've ever seen. I could read it in the doc.

Comment: Why is it the "worst" if it is taken directly from the docs? Maybe provide a "better" explanation instead of bashing the only answer, which the OP deemed to be sufficient enough to check.

Comment: there's no point copying the doc here, the question was asked because the doc didn't explained it well, otherwise, the question wasn't here at all. I can't explain this topic as well, that's why the answer bothers me that much. For the same reason, I could also copy & paste the doc. here.

Comment: Some people don't read the docs, unfortunately. Obviously it helped because it is the accepted answer. This community is about helping others, not trying to tear them down. If it bothers you that much, provide a better answer. You stumbled upon this because you were probably asking the same question and you can't figure it out, so you post a negative comment.